# It is possible to visualize the load of an APC switched PDU for a specified period of time?

Tags: datacenter, ups, infrastructure, apc, power-distribution-unit

There are some APC PDUs AP7953 and now we think about a solution for check the load over a period. We don't need a 100% correct Value only a trend on which hours we have more load to localize peeks in the Powernetwork.

If I log into the PDU I can see the current load, can I set a option to log every change of the current load, so I can write a script that make a Graph for it, but I can't find such a Option. Should I use SNMP for it or is there any other possibility?

I take a look to Gude Expert PDU Energy 8185 but this is very expensive and we don't need 100% correct values. Any tips for this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to visualize the load of an APC switched PDU for a specified period of time.

You can easily graph it via SNMP using any number of [network monitoring tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems). APC equipment is ubiquitous, so support for the device is rarely a problem.
[image]

You can view the tabular data directly through the unit's web interface and even graph it in Microsoft Excel if you don't wish to set up a monitoring solution and need to review performance on an as-needed basis.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/).  It's a simple RRDtool-based Graphing system. I wrote a [quick-start guide to Munin back in 2011](http://tomoconnor.eu/blogish/monitoring-munin/#.UhM-SJLvuW0)

You could similarly use StatsD/Graphite, but Munin probably has the simplest learning curve, and fastest ROI.

Then you'll need to have a look at the SNMP output of the device, probably `snmpwalk` is the easiest way to do this.

You can download the MIB (Management Information Base) for the APC PDUs from [here](http://www.observium.org/svn/observer/trunk/mibs/PowerNet-MIB), that'll help you get some intelligent output from the SNMP data.

APC [publish a document](http://www.apcmedia.com/salestools/ASTE-6Z5QEY/ASTE-6Z5QEY_R0_EN.pdf) that might aid you in figuring out how to interpret the SNMP+MIB output.

Once you know the OID of the data you wish to retrieve, have a read of the [Munin SNMP guide](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/Using_SNMP_plugins) to figure out how to use SNMP data in munin graphs.

I wouldn't bother scraping the output of a logfile, as SNMP is a far lower overhead method.